# How can I make a php tag search field with AND and OR conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, tags

I am trying to create a search field where people can search with tags that are saved in our database (ajax). The problem is that I want the user to be able to search with tags for content, where the content MUST have tags attached that include all the tags that were used for the search. So let's say I search for 'bwm red', I want to only show content with both the tags 'bmw' and 'red' attached to it. So NO content with only one of the two tags.

Additionally, the user can search for tags that are optional, so let's say the user searches for 'red yellow', the results should be content either with tags 'red' or 'yellow', where it also matches with the MUST search field. By doing so you get a very specific search.

In the photo here I have included the design how the search field should work, and it should be more clear what I am trying to create.

[image]

I have also written some code, but as you can see it is not working how I want to be.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

```
<form action="search.php" method="post" >
    <h2>Search Keywords:</h2>
    <h3>MUST</h3>
    <input type="text" name="must">
    <h3>Optional</h3>
    <input type="text" name="keyword">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
      $aMust = explode(" ", $_POST['must']);
      $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword']);
      $query ="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'";

     for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
        if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
            $query .= " OR field1 like '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%'";
        }
      }

     $result = $db->query($query);
     echo "<br>You have searched for keywords: " . $_POST['keyword'];

     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row_count=0;
        echo "<br>Result Found: ";
        echo "<br><table border='1'>";
        While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
            $row_count++;                         
            echo "<tr><td> ROW ".$row_count." </td><td>". $row['field1'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br>Result Found: NONE";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UNION to get the records and show data like below

```
$aMust = explode(" ", $_POST['must']);
$aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword']);

$query ="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (";
for($i = 0; $i < count($aMust); $i++) {
    if( $i!=0 && $i != (count($aMust)-1) ) {
        $query .=" AND ";
    }
    if(!empty($aMust[$i])) {
        $query .=" field1 like '%" . $aMust[$i] . "%' ";
    }
}
$query .=" ) ";

if( count($aKeyword) > 0 ) {
   $query .= " AND (";
   for($i = 0; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
      if( $i!=0 && $i != (count($aKeyword)-1) ) {
          $query .=" OR ";
      }
      if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
         $query .= " field1 like '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%'";
      }
   }
   $query .= " ) ";
}

$query .=" UNION ";
$query .=" SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (";
for($i = 0; $i < count($aMust); $i++) {
    if( $i!=0 && $i != (count($aMust)-1) ) {
        $query .=" AND ";
    }
    if(!empty($aMust[$i])) {
        $query .=" field1 like '%" . $aMust[$i] . "%' ";
    }
}
$query .=" ) ";
```

This will give you those records which matches the optional values and which do not matches the optional values but matches the must values.

UNION do not gives duplicate records, so you don't have to worry for duplicate values coming.

In case any issue, let me know in comments.

Comment: @user2980782, I have made a edit, please check with new edit.

Comment: @user2980782, did you tried with new update in answer. Bcoz I tried the above formatted query and got same results as mentioned in photo attached.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah I tried the new code (: But how do I echo the search results?

Comment: did the query formatted gave you the results? You can echo the query to know what is formed and run in phpmyadmin or any software you use, also get the results in the same as you are getting now.

Comment: So I used the same method $result = $db->query($query); to echo the result, but I get an error back saying "( ! ) Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\mtut\search.php on line 51
"

Comment: can you show the code written in $db->query(). As there is a problem in that function. Also, did you tried to echo "$query" variable before calling $db->query().

Comment: echo the $query literally gives me the sql code "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 like '%%' AND ( ) UNIONSELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 like '%%'"

Comment: Why you are calling mysqli_num_rows, is there no function created in library of object $db. And Put some space before and after "UNION" word.

Comment: So I added the space before and after UNION, and I tested the code with echo $query; and I get the following https://i.imgur.com/5JxhDrf.jpg
The sql doesn't include the search terms, is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure why I use mysqli_num_rows...do you know the code on how to echo the results for this particular query as well? (: Because simple echo $query; does not work.

Comment: @user2980782, I have made some edits in code, please make them in yours and send me the image same as above.

Comment: Thank you! I just applied the code, and it is not doing what it should do I think? https://i.imgur.com/su6TLAN.jpg

Comment: I got the error, start your for loop with $i=0 not with $i=1. As it picks the second value after explode. Also, check my updated code.